# Links Going Blank on Resizing

Tags: javascript, html, css, ipad, wordpress

For some reason, when I shrink the browser screen (chrome) on windows (not mac), or rotate on an ipad, the link color goes from white on black to white on white. The hover effect still works, but the links just completely disappear.

see here: http://www.keganquimby.com/pf/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've this rule:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1023px) and (min-width: 768px) {
    #main-nav ul li a {
        color: #fff;
    }
}
```

On line 4798 of style.css i guess it's the cause.

Answer (score 2):

Here's your problem

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1023px) and (min-width: 768px)
#main-nav ul li a {
    color: white;
}
```

You have seted the link color to white, change that and it will work